# Skaffold dev with remote docker context

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, skaffold

I am working on a web application with all the infrastructure based on Kubernetes. In my local environment, I am using Skaffold.
I have two computers (Desktop and Laptop) with 8Gb of RAM each. By starting minikube (virtualbox driver) and `skaffold dev` the Deskop is freezing.

So I decided to use the Laptop for coding and the Desktop for running minikube and everything related.

I successfully managed to set up **kubeconfig** on the laptop to have a context with the minikube server.

Actually, The issue is skaffold.
When I run `skaffold dev`, it fails because minikube of the Deskop doesn't see the images build by skaffold on my laptop. `kubectl get po` returns **ImagePullBackOff**.
That is because skaffold uses the local docker to build the image.
The question is *how to make skaffold use the docker install in my Desktop*?
I changed the docker context of my laptop so that it's linked to the Desktop context but it's still not working, skaffold is still using the default docker context installed in my laptop.

How to make the images build by Skaffold being available on my Desktop?
Is it possible for Skaffold to use a remote docker context? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Minikube uses its own Docker installation to power its cluster.  This daemon runs in Minikube's VM (or container, if using the `docker` driver) and is completely independent from the host's Docker daemon (your Desktop).  You can access to Minikube's daemon by setting the environment returned by `minikube docker-env`.

Comment: Please, how to modify that DOCKER_HOST variable? I would like to make minikube (from Desktop) to use the Docker context set up in the laptop

Comment: **I haven't tried this myself** but I think you might be able to use `eval $(minikube docker-env --ssh-host)`.  If using the Docker runtime, you may need to start minikube with `--network host`.  If using a VM-based runtime, where the VM will have a separate IP, then you may need to configure an SSH`JumpHost` https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump